# powershell signing certificate unknownerror

Tags: powershell, certificate, signing, authenticode

I am following the instructions to [sign a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_signing?view=powershell-7.2)

and I've got to the part where I sign the `add-signature.ps1` file so that I can sign my script using it

```
$cert = @(Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My -codesigning)[0]
Set-AuthenticodeSignature add-signature.ps1 $cert
```

and I get this error:
[image]

I've Googled endlessly but found no solutions!
I'm running PS in Administrator mode and I've set the policy for CurrentUser to AllSigned

[image]

Can anyone help me? Do I need to set all the policies to AllSigned?

UPDATE:
Deleting all the Certs and starting again, following the Microsoft instructions:
[image]
and of course I get an error when I try to run the add-signature.ps1 script - help!

Comment: You need to trust your certificate by running your script and select `always run` or put it in the conerned trusted stores, see https://adamtheautomator.com/how-to-sign-powershell-script/#:~:text=Signing%20a%20PowerShell%20Script,-Now%20that%20you&text=When%20you%20need%20to%20sign,local%20machine%27s%20personal%20certificate%20store.

Comment: Als a good reference: [Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Sign Windows PowerShell Scripts with an Enterprise Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-sign-windows-powershell-scripts-with-an-enterprise-windows-pki-part-1-of-2/)

Comment: Thanks @iRon, but I don't even get the prompt to 'always run'. I've deleted all the CurrentUser certificates and started again, but I still get the UnknownError

Comment: @MarcusR1 Make sure the certificate is trusted by adding it to `cert:\CurrentUser\TrustedPublisher\`. Make sure the certificate is valid for code signing in `$codeCertificate.EnhancedKeyUsageList`. Try and run `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` without the `-TimestampServer` flag.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: thanks @Cpt.Whale I'm sorry about the delay, I got pulled onto another project. So I've imported the certificate into the TrustedPublisher and tried again but still get UnknownError - I have verified that the cert and the import are there using Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -CodeSigningCert -Recurse     BUT I still get UnknownError when running Set-AuthenticodeSignature (without Timestamp) - I am losing what little hair I have!

Answer (score 0):

Importing the cert to \CurrentUser\Root as well as TrustedPublisher worked

Comment: This is not an answer.  You should accept the proposed answer, not add another 'answer' that is not an answer.  Or in a case where the answer came as a comment, follow the instructions on how to answer your own question.  Hint: list the steps required and briefly explain.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @KenBrittain please don't encourage users to edit solutions into their question.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question after following the same [instructions for signing a Powershell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_signing) mentioned by @MarcusR1. And I as well was running into the same issue with the `UnknownError` when signing my Powershell script.

I eventually found a working solution in [Powershell's Github repository](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4753#issuecomment-341851925). Following the original instructions from Microsoft's instructions I was able to successfully sign my Powershell script by running the following commands:

```
Export-Certificate -FilePath exported_cert.cer -Cert $cert
Import-Certificate -FilePath exported_cert.cer -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\Root

Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Certificate $cert -FilePath HelloWorld.exe
```